# Derivative of trace of product of matrices

Tags: derivatives, trace

How to find the derivative of $$L=trace(A\left( \theta \right)^{-1}B\left( \theta \right))$$ wrt to $\theta \mathbf{}$. Where $A\left( \theta \right) $ and $B\left( \theta \right) $ are square
matrices, and are functions of some vector of parameters $\theta \mathbf{.}$ Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the derivative of ${\rm inv}\colon A \mapsto A^{-1}$ is given by
$$ D(\def\i{{\rm inv}}\i)(A)H = -A^{-1}HA $$
Hence, by the chain and the product rule, we have, as ${\rm trace}$ is linear: 
$$ DL(\theta)(h) = {\rm trace}\bigl(A(\theta)^{-1}DB(\theta)h\bigr)
     - {\rm trace}\bigl(A(\theta)^{-1}DA(\theta)h \,A(\theta)^{-1}B(\theta)\bigr) $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider your function $L:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Then if you want to find the derivative of $L$ at $\theta_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ in direction $\hat\theta\in T_\theta\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^n$, you can simply compute
$$(D_\theta L)(\hat\theta) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}L(\theta + t\hat\theta).$$

Comment: Thanks. Can we get an explicit expression of the partial derivatives or is there any reference I can refer to?

Comment: @CharlesChou I don't know of any references, but also notice that the trace is a linear map, so it will commute with the derivative. You are left with using a product rule and differentiating a inverse (**hint:** use $A(\theta)A(\theta)^{-1}=1$, differentiate both sides)